# SSH a ethernet connected device via Google WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh

This is my setting:

Modem/Router *-LAN->* Google WiFI *-WiFi->* MacBook
Modem/Router *-LAN->* Raspberry Pi

Now, I want to connect via SSH from my MacBook terminal to the Raspberry Pi.

Please note that my Modem/Router has no WiFi. So I will need to reach the Raspberry Pi with this route:

MacBook *-WiFi->* Google WiFi *-LAN->* Modem/Router *-LAN->* Raspberry Pi.

I know my Raspberry Pi IP but on my terminal and with this setting

`ssh pi@192.168.1.110` returns `ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.110 port 22: Operation timed out`.

EDIT: This setup used to work before Google WiFi was added.

Comment: Did you activate the ssh daemon?

Comment: That should just work, unless the Google Wi-Fi thingy does something terribly strange.

Comment: You are running an SSH server on that machine, and it does use the port on which you are trying to connect, but the machine has a firewall that does not allow you to connect to it. You'll need to figure out how to change the firewall, or maybe you need to ssh from a different host to be allowed in.

Comment: @pythonian When you say `on that machine` do you mean the Google WiFI or the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @Francesco - Sorry, please check both the Macbook and the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @pythonian it used to work before I started using the Google Wifi

Comment: @Francesco - Oh! You should add that bit of information to the original question.  Sorry, I know nothing about Google WiFi - You may want to experiment with Port Forwarding, even though it's an issue on your local network.

Comment: Did you perhaps set the Wi-Fi network to be in some sort of guest mode? Your access point may then drop all traffic that isn’t Internet-bound. /edit: Google recommends connecting all network devices to your Google Wi-Fi instead of any upstream devices.

Comment: @Francesco Note sure if this might help, but Google WiFi does support port forwarding. Also, port 22 might be locked down. Regarding some specifics, you might want to look at this [Google Product Forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/googlewifi/QXViBrugtNc).